# How do I allow cloning from my git server with https?

Tags: git, ubuntu, https, server, virtualbox

I have a git server with different repositories set up in a VirtualBox (Lubuntu).

If I clone the repository from the other VM with the command:

```
 git clone ssh://git@192.168.1.120/home/git/myproject.git
```

it works as expected (after typing in the password from the user 'git').

What I want to accomplish, is to clone the repository via **https** like:

```
git clone https://192.168.1.120/home/git/myproject.git
```

but I get the error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://192.168.1.120/home/git/myproject.git':
Failed to connect to 192.168.1.120 port 443: Connection refused
```

The key of the VM, which wants to fetch the repository is already copied into the folder ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the git server.

I would be happy if somebody could give me a hint on this.

EDIT: Apache2 is running now and the port 443 is working. I am able to open the folder with the repositories in the browser and see all repos when typing

```
https://192.168.1.120/git/
```

then I can browse through the directories. But when I execute

```
git clone https://192.168.1.120/git/myproject.git
```

it fails with the error:

```
fatal: repository 'https://192.168.1.120/git/myproject.git/' not found
```

I assume the path is correct, since it is the same as used in the webbrowser.

Comment: Well, you need to setup a https server, that is not done automagically somehow.

Comment: @arkascha The apache2 server is running, but probably not configured correctly

Comment: You would need to install a [server certificate](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-and-install-an-apache-self-signed-certificate.html) and configure apache to listen on that port as well as setting up a host file (virtual host) that points to your git root. I would [google setup git server ubuntu](https://www.google.es/search?q=setup+git+server+ubuntu&oq=setup+git+server+&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.15361j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and follow one of the examples there.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Will try it tomorrow immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, if you don't have a running web server giving you a view onto your repository, there's no chance to connect to it, since it's not Git business to run these services. Furthermore, your hypothetical server is VERY UNLIKELY to directly expose your filesystem's root on the net.

If you do already have a running web server that is known to be properly configured, well you already known that it's not currently listening on **HTTPS** (calling it from HTTP through regular port 80 should work). But in any case, the resulting URL won't be `//192.168.1.120/home/git/myproject.git`. You'll have to define a web repository on your machine (usually `/var/www/html`) that will be seen as the root of your server from the outside.